# how to get current page after refresh using vue router?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

i try using vue router js in laravel, but i get problem when i refresh the page, laravel say "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.", i know this problem from web.php laravel the route not be found and then i try this code in web.php

```
Route::get('/{name}', function() {
   return redirect('/');
});
```

so when i try refresh page in url "127.0.0.1:8000/home" it will redirect in "127.0.0.1:8000".

but it's not like I wanted,  I wanted was get the same page when refreshing the current page.

please help me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the [`history` mode](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html#mode) in your router, you must [properly configure your server-side app](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) to serve the Vue application on any request that matches route declared in your Vue router.

This could be as simple as a blanket catch-all route to serve the main view.

Comment: I'm still confused :D

Comment: All traffic has to go to whatever template you have that has the Vue application running in it.

Comment: ok thanks @Marty i will try to configure my server-side app like in documentation :)